# "In" keyword doesn't work to check if string available in the list of tuples

Tags: python-3.x, list, tuples

Got a list which contains tuples of Strings and I need to check if the given string is within any of the tuples or not, I'm able to do that with my piece of code but I'm looking for a pythonic way of doing this and also the "in" doesn't work here like 'GivenName' in namelst.

Tuple:

```
namelst= [('Travolta', 'Surname'), ('John', 'GivenName'), ('Joe', 'Nickname')]
```

Traditional Code:

```
for items in namelst:
    if('GivenName' in items):
        //Do Something
```

Comment: Do you need the tuple that matched? Or do you just need to know whether there is a match or not?

Comment: No i don't need the tuple, Only boolean..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to know whether there was a match or not, just using `any` should be enough -

```
if any('GivenName' in x for x in namelst):
    ... # do something
```

`any` performs short circuiting on every boolean result generated as a result of the comprehension. Once the *first* `True` result is found, iteration stops and the resultant is `True`. Otherwise, iteration completes and if no `True` result was encountered, the result if `False`.

Contrast this operation with `all` which works the opposite way, returning the first `False` value it finds, or `True` otherwise.

---

If you need to find the *first* index that matched, you can just use `next`, which happens to be very efficient and will not iterate over the entire `namelst` if it isn't needed -

```
j = next((i for i, x in enumerate(namelst) if 'GivenName' in x), -1)
if j > -1:
    ... # do something
```

On a related note, if you want to find *every* index that matched, a `for` loop is not only the most pythonic, but the simplest solution.

```
for i, x in enumerate(namelst):
    if 'GivenName' in x:
        ... # do something
```

The assumption with the last two solutions is that you'd need the index to do something (hence, the use of `enumerate`).

Answer (score -1):

In the If command remove braces and try like this

> `if 'Given name' in items:`

Above line worked for me

Comment: The problem is not with the if command, I'm looking for a pythonic way to check this and wanted to understand why "in" keyword is not working as explained in the Question.

Comment: Working for me. And excuse me if I understood your problem wrong!

Comment: Did it work by returning False? Because that means it didn't work.

Comment: @KeyserSoze you are doing 'Given name' in items, what I was looking for 'Given name' in namelst, which is list of tuples. whereas items is the individual tuple.